# Linq result from many tables into an inherit class with nested classes

Tags: c#, linq, nested, entity-framework-6

I've got an SQL table but the customer removed all the foreign keys and won't let me rebuild table with all the foreign keys.

I've used Entity Framework on a database first approach, I've got something like :

```
public class MainTable
{
    MainTableID,
    TableChildOneID,
    TableChildTwoID,
    //... many properties
}

public class TableChildOne
{
    TableChildOneID,
    //... many properties
}

public class TableChildTwo
{
    TableChildTwoID,
    //... many properties
}
```

I've created a class which represents the "real" linked nested class like :

```
public class MainTable_Extended : MainTable
{
    public TableChildOne ChildOne { get; set; }
    public TableChildTwo ChildTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the MainTable contains a lot of properties

Here's the query where I'm looking for a clean syntax

```
IQueryable<MainTable_Extended> listMainTable =
            from main in db.MainTable
            from childone in db.TableChildOne.Where(childone => childone.TableChildOneID == main.TableChildOneID).DefaultIfEmpty()
            from childtwo in db.TableChildTwo.Where(childtwo => childtwo.TableChildTwoID == main.TableChildTwoID).DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new MainTable_Extended
            {
                ChildOne = childone ,
                ChildTwo = childtwo ,
                All others properties coming from => main 
            };
```

How do I populate my class MainTable_Extended without doing it by hand for all properties.

Comment: How do you expect the code to "guess" what your relationships are? You need to tell it, if you can't do that by DB schema then you must do it manually

Comment: I think a join would be better instead of three "from".

Comment: I used from with DefaultIfEmpty() because I wanted a LEFT OUTTER JOIN and it seems that using join will do a INNER JOIN

Comment: @HassanN So your problem is that you want the propertys form the MainTable_Extended Class ?

Comment: Basically i've got three table not linked by EF and I wanted to query the mainTable with left outter join the two child table and populate the result in a class hierarchy

Comment: When starting in project I've done it with foreign keys and using Include but the customer told me to not touch at all the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works for you?

```
public class MainTable
   {
       public int MainTableID;
       public int TableChildOneID;
       public int TableChildTwoID;
       //... many properties
   }

public class TableChildOne
   {
       public int TableChildOneID;
       //... many properties
   }

public class TableChildTwo
   {
       public int TableChildTwoID;
       //... many properties
   }

public class MainTable_Extended
   {
       public TableChildOne ChildOne { get; set; }
       public TableChildTwo ChildTwo { get; set; }
       public MainTable Main { get; set; }
   }

public class DB : DbContext
   {
       public DB()
           : base("name=YourName")
       {}

       public virtual DbSet<MainTable> MainTables { get; set; }
       public virtual DbSet<TableChildOne> TableChildOnes { get; set; }
       public virtual DbSet<TableChildTwo> TableChildTwos { get; set; }
   }

public class Test
   {
      public void TestTest()
        {
           var db = new DB();

           IQueryable<MainTable_Extended> listMainTable =
           from main in db.MainTables
           from childone in db.TableChildOnes.Where(childone => childone.TableChildOneID == main.TableChildOneID).DefaultIfEmpty()
           from childtwo in db.TableChildTwos.Where(childtwo => childtwo.TableChildTwoID == main.TableChildTwoID).DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new MainTable_Extended
            {
               ChildOne = childone,
               ChildTwo = childtwo,
               Main = main
            };
        }
    }
```

I let the `MainTable_Extended class` not inhier from the `MainTable class`. Instead i make a property with a MainTable object. So in the query i give the `MainTable_Extended` a value for the property.

So no you can query the propertys of `MainTable` by call the property `Main` of `MainTable_Extended`.

Comment: Please explain why this should help the OP,  this is not helping him if you don't say what you are thinking and why you did it like this.

Comment: @JordyvanEijk yes you are right. That was my bad, thanks for your notice!

Comment: Hi Darem, it is currently working like you've done as a work around, I post the question if someone knows how to do that with inherit

Comment: @HassanN ok sorry that i cant help

Comment: @Darem No worries I will wait and if no answer i will accept this workaround